# Splitting items in a list into two and appending one of them to another list

Tags: python

Hey all. Trying to get a little more efficient with lists in Python but I cant seem to figure out if I can do what I want or even if it is worth figuring out.

stream is a list. Each item in the list is something like :

10,123400FFFE001DB9AA

I am trying to get to the second part of each item after the comma so I run through the list splitting each one and storing it in temp . I them append temp[1) to the other list called incoming_data.

I would like to combine the line that splits and saves to temp and appends to the incoming_data list into one line, something like:

incoming_data.append(item.split(','))

I know the above syntax is totally incorrect but I hope it gets the point across. Here is my current code.

Other critiques welcome as usual. Thanks!

```
#init the final list
incoming_data = list()

#iterate over each item in the list
for item in stream:

      #clear the temp variable for next time
      temp = ''

      #we sometimes get blank items in the stream list so check first
      if item <> '':

             #split each item in the stream list using the comma as delimiter
             temp = item.split(',')

             #append to the final data lis
             incoming_data.append(temp[1])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
incoming_data = [item.split(",")[1] for item in stream if item]
```

The `if item` discards the blank lines in `stream`.

Comment: Ah, +1 for catching the blank line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's handy-dandy [list comprehensions](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pytut/ListComprehensions.html) to do this in one line:

```
incoming_data = [ item.split(',')[1] for item in stream ]
```

Comment: Ninja'ed! And @RichardFearn's response is better to include the `if item` at the end!

Comment: Watch out for blank lines :-) (See my answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you *could* do `incoming_data.append(item.split(',')[1])`. If you really wanted you could combine the whole shebang into a one liner using a list comprehension (mine is now corrected for the blank line thanks to Richard):

`incoming_data = [item.split(',')[0] for item in stream if item]`

Though if you're actually streaming something you should look at [generators(PDF)](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/Generators.pdf) - they're absolutely amazing.